# Calculate Mean and Variance of function output

Tags: r, function, random, statistics, poisson

I have the following code which outputs 1000 MLEs, how do I calculate the mean and variance of the output and include it into the function?
I want the output to be; f2d(5) = mean value and variance value

```
f2d = function(n){
  fun = function(y){
    optimise(
      function(theta){ sum(dpois(y, theta, log = TRUE)) }, 
      interval = c(0,50), 
      maximum = TRUE
    )
  }
# apply the function to each poisson sample
  x = replicate(1000, rpois(n, 10))
  apply(x, 2, fun)
  }
```

Comment: You could use `mean` and `var`

Comment: It's not clear what you need, Monj. Do you want the mean/var out of `f2d` or out of `fun`? Do you want the mean and variance to *replace* or *augment* the current return value? How do you want the output structured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`optimise` returns a named list with two elements, `maximum` and `objective`. The mean/variance (lambda) for `dpois` is going to be `maximum`. Have `fun` return just `maximum`:

```
f2d <- function(n){
  fun = function(y){
    optimise(
      function(theta){ sum(dpois(y, theta, log = TRUE)) }, 
      interval = c(0,50), 
      maximum = TRUE
    )$maximum
  }
  # apply the function to each poisson sample
  x = replicate(1000, rpois(n, 10))
  apply(x, 2, fun)
}
```

BTW, since the MLE of lambda is the mean of the observations and sums of Poisson random variables are also Poisson-distributed, you could replace `f2d` with

```
f2d <- function(n) rpois(1e3, 10*n)/n
```